# How to write jquery-ui options in a concise way?

Tags: jquery-ui

This is my jQuery codes

```
$("#divAddExistingPath").dialog('open');
$("#divAddExistingPath").dialog('option', 'width', 700);
$("#divAddExistingPath").offset({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left })
```

It looks like I may have to write more and more lines to get extra functionality. Is there any way concise way to write this jquery?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Use chaining wherever it's possible.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: At first, it would be good if you have the default options set in the dialog constructor. Then, you would need to change options just if different from those previous values. To chain methods, just do like this: `$("#foo").offset(bar).dialog("open")`

Comment: offset is a method. But the first lines are both part of the dialog method. And each time I put them together they don't work. Do you know how to chain the 'open' and 'width'?